# Database - Remove Everything After

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am pretty new to modifying databases (running phpmyadmin for WooCommerce) and I am currently stuck at a problem.

Basically I have around 400 items which have random SKUs (example).

```
JCB-5018057409641_888
OX TOOLS-5060242330476_870
REFINA-281314_856
```

I need to mass remove for everything going from the underscore and the 3 numbers.

I think I could possibly use Sublime or Notepad++ to achieve this but looking through many queries I can't seem to do it right.

Answer (score 2):

If the column never has an underscore other than the one you want to remove, you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
update yourtable set yourcolumn = substring_index(yourcolumn,'_',1);
```